# Generating a timestamp to usec accuracy in shell (Busybox)

Tags: unix, shell, date-time, busybox

I want to generate a textual timestamp in the unix shell with microsecond accuracy, without using the `%N` date option (I am using busybox, a smaller unix toolset that does not have this option), to prefix to output I am generating. The timestamp should have the format `"<seconds since epoc>.<microseconds>"`.

```
awk -f ./myawkscript.awk < /param | sed 's/$/\[<TIMESTAMP WOULD GO HERE>].'
```

So the desired output would look like:

```
[1305638345.123456] awk script output
```

I can obtain the epoc easy enough using `date +"%s"`, so my question is, is there a way of obtaining the microseconds from the shell?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main() {
    struct timeval t;

    if (gettimeofday(&t, NULL) == 0)
        printf("%d.%06u\n", t.tv_sec, t.tv_usec);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile with `cc -o timestamp timestamp.c`

For completeness: `clock_gettime()` can return nanoseconds, but with an `awk` script you wouldn't reach that accuracy anyway.

Comment: If you have a `cc` command, you're probably not on a system that has to use BusyBox for its shell and utilities.